# Ansible log in as regular user and become root

Tags: ssh, root, ansible

using the new "become" syntax, how do you configure your playbook to log in to a host as a regular user, switch to the root user and ask for a password?

I tried:

```
---
- hosts: foo
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: martin
  become: yes
  become_method: su

  tasks:
  - name: update
    yum: name=tree state=latest
```

This playbook just hands in the `TASK` phase. I also tried removing the `become_method` and using `ansible-playbook book.yml --ask-become-pass` but that also didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to use `sudo`?

Comment: @Jakuje I know how to make it work with `sudo` and `su` but I'm looking for how to do this with the `become` directives. I do not use sudo on the target machine, only a plain root account.

Comment: Please post the error message otherwise it is not possible to tell what is going wrong. Is the user `martin` able to use the `su` command?

Comment: @knowhy There is no error, it just hangs after `TASK: [update]`. Running it with `-vvvv` shows that it tries to execute `-c 'su root -c "/bin/sh -c <command>` but it needs to ask a password for that to succeed, which never happens.

Comment: So `sudo: yes` is working but `become: yes` is not? But @Jakuje has a point, with "did you try `sudo`?" - not as `sudo: yes` but as `become_method: sudo` (which is the default if omitted)

Comment: I believe if you set `become_method: su` you need to provide root password with `--ask-become-pass` as Ansible will login with `remote_user` and gain privilege with `su`. Maybe adding `become_user: root` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think I hit something similar to this recently and ended up putting these lines in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become=Yes
become_method=sudo
become_user=root
become_ask_pass=True
```

I think the `become_user` directive is unnecessary as thats also the default, but I think it was the `become_ask_pass` that made the difference and stopped it hanging.

Hope that helps.